# Solving $1^x+2^x+3^x=0$ equations...

Tags: complex-numbers, exponential-function, graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha, transcendental-equations

Is it possible to solve for x this kind of equation? Since 1,2,3 are not multiples to each other I see a priori no possibility.
$$1^x+2^x+3^x=0; x?$$

Computing this on Wolfram Alpha, for example,  returns two complex solutions for $x$. Wolfram Alpha usually returns a formal and <strike>algebraical</strike> expression to represent the solution, but this time no formal one is returned, instead, just a long, infinite and complex number with seems to be the result of an iterating computation rather than a formal way to solve it.

You can check the results with Newton-Rhapson's method in [my GeoGebra's plot.](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/fju8an9q)

Comment: I've voted this up as it leads to an interesting project.

Comment: For the complex zeros $|2^z+3^z| < 1 $ for $ \Re(z) > 1$ and $|3^{-z}+(3/2)^{-z}| < 1$ for $\Re(x) < -1$ so the zeros are located in a strip $\Re(x) \in [-1,1]$. There is at least one zero at $-0.454397 \pm 3.59817i$ and by almost periodicity there are infinitely many of them, almost linear spaced vertically.

Comment: I guess one of the problems is I pretend to find an analytical solution for a transcendental equation...

Comment: @Fco. Javier López I've added an image of the zero at -0.45+3.59 plus a link to the free webpage complex grapher used to obtain it

Answer (score 4):

It certainly can't have any real value solutions since,
$$1^x+2^x+3^x=0$$
$$1+2^x+3^x=0$$
$$2^x+3^x=-1$$
And $a^x>0$ for all real $x$ and all real $a>0$.

So it makes sense that if you want a solution, the search needs the extended number system of complex numbers.

If you ask Wolfram Alpha to solve
$$2^x+3^x=-1$$
it will give you the numerical solutions
$$x=-0.454397 \pm 3.59817i$$

If you want to try and obtain these by hand you could try applying the numerical Newton Raphson method to the equation; it works with complex numbers as well as the reals, but the arithmetic may be daunting especially if you are interested in solutions to
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^x=0$$

To explore this properly would need software that can apply the Newton Raphson method in complex numbers and show you what it's doing.

A quick google search makes me think Maxima may do it for free : http://maxima.sourceforge.net/
or GNU Octave : http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/
although I have no experience of either, or even if they can cope with complex numbers.

The irony is, of course, that you ideally want to start near a solution. I see this is becoming an interesting project; be good to graph the modulus of the complex function for small values of k, as often done for Zeta function.

Update:
There's a free interactive Complex Grapher embedded within a webpage which I've used to look at the zero at -0.45+3.59i which is shown at the black centre of the coloured circle.

[image: The zero at -0.45+3.59i]

The webpage is here : https://www.complexgrapher.com/

Comment: I know. But how do you solve it?

Comment: I've added the numerical answers to my post, but I agree with your original question which said these look like solutions obtained by iteration rather than symbolic manipulation

Comment: The key problem is the initial guess. Suppose that we have the equation $\sum_{k=2}^n k^x=-1$ where $n$ is given, any idea for $x_0=a+b i$ ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovici I've added a reply to my answer as the limit on the length of comment prevented it going here.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is just ONE solution. Depending on the branch cut, there are many other solutions.

Comment: @TomislavOstojich That's true. In [this link](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/fju8an9q) you can find a plot of the 1^x+2^x+3^x function and also the graphical representation of the Newton-Rhapson's method for getting all the solutions. Move with the mouse the blue dot to see where do the other points converge to, to see other solutions from other branch cuts.

Answer (score 3):

*Too long for a comment.*

After @Martin Hansen's answer, I had a look to he zero of equation
$$f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^x$$
(give a lot of attention to @reuns's comment).

I used Newton method. For the base case $(n=3)$ starting with $x_0=-1+\pi\,i$ the iterates are

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -0.501820 \,+ \,3.86512 \,i \\
 2 & -0.487049 \,+ \,3.58176\,i \\
 3 & -0.454116 \,+ \,3.59875 \,i \\
 4 & -0.454397 \,+ \,3.59817\, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Below are given some results which could be a good start (I hope) for a deeper exploration (as @Martin Hansen suggested).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 3 &  -0.454397\, + \,3.59817 \, i \\
 4 &  -0.625971\, + \,3.12712 \, i \\
 5 &  -0.714285\, + \,2.83349 \, i \\
 6 &  -0.767633\, + \,2.62901 \, i \\
 7 &  -0.803209\, + \,2.47644 \, i \\
 8 &  -0.828584\, + \,2.35711 \, i \\
 9 &  -0.847585\, + \,2.26049 \, i \\
 10 & -0.862348\, + \,2.18022 \, i \\
 11 & -0.874153\, + \,2.11212 \, i \\
 12 & -0.883812\, + \,2.05341 \, i \\
 13 & -0.891868\, + \,2.00209 \, i \\
 14 & -0.898692\, + \,1.95672 \, i \\
 15 & -0.904551\, + \,1.91623 \, i \\
 16 & -0.909640\, + \,1.87978 \, i \\
 17 & -0.914103\, + \,1.84675 \, i \\
 18 & -0.918051\, + \,1.81661 \, i \\
 19 & -0.921571\, + \,1.78897 \, i \\
 20 & -0.924730\, + \,1.76349 \, i
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: How long did it take to you to converge to the root? (How many iterations)

Comment: @Fco.JavierLópez. It is not bad. I shall add details tomorrow morning. By the way, if I may ask, where are you located ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeivici I'm located in Spain.

Comment: @Fco.JavierLópez. Pues, somos vecinos, amigo !