# Roots of $f(x)=3^x+4^x-5^x$

Tags: real-analysis, roots

Let define $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as $f(x)=3^x+4^x-5^x$.

Prove that there exists only one $x_0$ such as $f(x_0)=0$.

**My approach:**

We can see that $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f(2)=0$. I don't know how to use the derivatives of $f$ to prove that it is firstly increasing and then decreasing for $x\in(-\infty,2)$ and for $x\in(2,\infty)$ it is only decreasing.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61812/proving-that-2-is-the-only-real-solution-of-3x4x-5x

Comment: It's a more interesting question when the solutions to this sort of equation are allowed to be complex : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140553/solving-1x2x3x-0-equations/3140565#3140565

Answer (score 4):

For $x>2$ we have $3^{x}+4^{x}=(9)3^{x-2}+(16)4^{x-2}<(9)5^{x-2}+(16)5^{x-2}=5^{x}$ and the inequalities gets reversed for $x<2$. Hence $x=2$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

Easier way to see it is
$$
3^x+4^x=5^x \qquad\Longleftrightarrow\qquad f(x)=\left(\frac{3}{5}\right)^x
+\left(\frac{4}{5}\right)^x-1=0
$$
Clearly, the left hand side is a strictly decreasing function as a sum of two strictly decreasing functions.

Also $f(2)=0$, and hence $x=2$ is the one and only root of $f$.